# Missed passport number by one digit when booking flight online

Tags: air-travel, passports

So I was booking a flight for me and friends from Beijing to Tokyo, but mistakenly missed a digit in a friend's passport. I did not check in online of course.

The flight's tomorrow. Will there be problems checking in at the airport?

Comment: My trip into China was delayed because the thai firm responsible for the visa omitted a leading zero. It caused about an hour or so's delay. It was obvious that everything else was correct apart from that missing digit. I have no idea what took them so long, or what needed to be done to allow the trip to continue; perhaps there's a gang of criminals who create perfect copies of passports/visas but who omit a single digit as their calling card. (Had this been on the way out of the country it would have perhaps made more sense; it was unclear why anyone would want to sneak into China.)

Comment: Don't worry, nobody actually checks that information: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-check-in-details-such-as-date-of-birth-or-passport

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call the airline's service hotline ASAP. They should be able to fix it or at least give a lot more authoritative information than we can.

Comment: Just thought I would add that I think it's valid to first ask here as it could've been that the general experiences were that they let it slip, but by calling the airline they might impose some ridiculous change passenger fee.

Answer (score 4):

It greatly depends on the airline. 
With some if you've already checked in, but put a wrong number in field, their might website let you "check-in again" during which you can fix the wrong digit.

Other airlines, you can only check-in once, and there's no way to undo it. So you'll have to go to the counter and tell them, you think you might have inputted an incorrect passport number by mistake. They are gonna check your passports anyways, specially if it's an international flight.

This has kinda happened to my mom, yet she had no trouble as I think the airline must have fixed it when she checked her bags and confirmed all the info.

I suspect airline employees familiar with the "tricky" passport numbers of specific countries can fix the issue. Or the system is build to handle the leading zeros and possible "format" variations.

Try to correct the info online on the airline's website first, if not possible,just *call them* to learn what do to. **Get to the airport with plenty of time though, JIC**