# DS160 connecting flight Atlanta keeps asking for location of stay but not staying

Tags: usa, transit-visas

My partner needs to get a visa.  From all I read it's a transit C-1 that is required.  I have flight details completed and it asks for location of stay in US.  Then contact in US. However we are only in the airport to get connecting flight.

Can anyone advise what I should be selecting or do I just type does not apply?

Comment: Has been answered a hundred times. Enter the address of the airport, or 'transit', or 'na'.

Comment: You could write "does not apply" or "not applicable." It might make more sense to write "transit" or "in transit." A related question can be found at http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/83416/19400.

Comment: 6000 N Terminal Pkwy, Atlanta, GA 30320