# When booking with Thomson Airways how can I select Lithuania as my country?

Tags: bookings, thomson-airways

When I try to book a flight on [Thomson](http://thomson.co.uk) airways website, I need to enter passenger and card holder address but there is no option to select my country (Lithuania) in the drop down list.

Can I book with incorrect residential or card holder country?

Is it strictly validated?

Can it be changed later without extra fees?

Comment: Do you mean there is *not* an option for your country?

Comment: Yes, edited, missed a word.

Comment: Is your country recognized by the UN? Many sites use that list to display options. Perhaps where you live is recognized under another name. In any case, I suspect you wont be able to pay either unless you have a CC from another country which is on their list.

Comment: Lithuania is recognized. Neighbouring countries like Poland or Latvia are in the list.

Comment: Lithuania is UN recognized. It is possible they simply do not have an agreement for payment processing, you should really call them and ask.

Comment: I have called them but their support does not say anything specific or gives phone number to other department which also can't help. Usually they suggest to make a booking via phone which can be made online by myself. Contacted via email too - waiting for response.

Comment: Why not go ahead and try? If it fails you know it doesn't work...

Comment: Let's say that the payment is successful and the flight is booked. But when I need to check-in online and possibly enter passport issuing country or nationality I may stuck with the same problem.

Comment: They don't check what document you entered during check-in: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-check-in-details-such-as-date-of-birth-or-passport. So you might as well put in Zimbabwe and no one would care. I'm afraid going for it is the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thomson misses some countries in the drop down list before payment. I have selected Latvia instead of UK because then the form does not validate phone number and ZIP. It didn't cause any problem, paid with non-UK credit card. During online check-in, I have found my country in the list.

Answer (score 3):

There are three addresses the airline might ask for.

When entering passenger **mailing address**, you generally can enter whatever you want, so in your case just enter some address in Latvia. I have never seen or heard of it to be ever checked. Notably many accepted travel documents - such as passports - do not have your address at all. Many years ago this address was used to send paper tickets to you, but nowadays the main purpose of asking for this seem to be that they could send you spam. The only exception is if you order a tour package from them, as they might need to send you paper vouchers or some other paperwork.

Passenger **billing address** is used by the credit card processor. Depending on the processor it might or might not matter (for example, in US for most processors only ZIP code matters). The easiest way to check this is to try to book and see if your payment is approved. If it is, you're generally good to go, although you might be asked to see your credit card at check-in.

Finally, passenger **destination address** in a destination country is asked by some airlines at check-in. This seem to be the requirement of the destination country's government, and passed to them by the airline as-is. Here you need to be careful, as making this one up might possibly lead to much more detailed immigration inspection such as when a friend of mine wrote that address as "under Brooklyn bridge".

PS. Glancing at this Thomson site, it misses quite a few countries.