# Can I change my citizenship (passport country) after booking a flight

Tags: air-travel, passports, tickets, canada, canadian-citizens

I want to book a flight from Toronto to Tokyo on Expedia and the flight date is Aug 14, 2017.

And Here is my situation:
Right now I have my Chinese passport. I just finished my Canadian citizenship test a week ago and I passed it, I am waiting for the oath of citizenship now. (oath will normally take place within six months after the test.) When I book my flight on Expedia, it asks my passport country, should I enter Canada or China?

If I enter my passport country as China, What should I do if I receive my Canadian Passport before the flight (which is Aug 14)? Can I still change my passport country after I booked and paid for my ticket? Any ideas or experiences?

Comment: I _think_ they don't care much what you enter, they only give you some hints about your visa situation that would depend on your answer. You should think about arriving in Tokyo with a Canadian passport, though (I have no idea what the visa needs are if any). Only when you check in, it _is_ relevant which country's passport you have, because depending on that, the airline will verify that you are allowed to get into Japan. Understand that it is _your_ problem, not Expedia's, if you buy a ticket that you cannot use for visa issues.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-check-in-details-such-as-date-of-birth-or-passport. TL;DR - no, nobody cares what you enter.

Comment: Will you lose your Chinese citizenship if you accept Canadian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a dual citizen, and I regularly check in using the passport other than the one I provided at booking. This has never caused a problem; no check-in agent has ever even mentioned it. So just check in with the passport you plan to use on arrival. It doesn't matter whether you gave that passport information when you booked.

If the airline asks about your other passport, just explain why you changed passports. There is nothing wrong with changing your citizenship.