# Booked a flight ticket with wrong passport number via a travel agency

Tags: tickets, expedia

I just purchased a flight ticket operated by Vietnam Airlines on Expedia, but I didn't notice the section on entering the passport number on the payment page on Expedia, and found that I completed the purchase without entering my passport number.

The problem was that I recently renewed my passport, and didn't edit my passport number on Expedia in advance.

So the ticket was purchased with my wrong passport number. In this case,

- Can I still change the passport number only or do I have to book a new flight ticket with the old one being a waste?
- Is it free of charge to change the passport number if it is possible? I got charged in Spring Airlines recently...
- Is it Expedia or Vietnam Airlines that I should contact?

Comment: In this particular case the best people to give you answers are the airline/Expedia. Will trump any advice or opinions you will get here. From my experience however, passport numbers are relatively simple and not like changing names where changing a name on a ticket requires voiding of the ticket and purchasing a new one altogether.

Comment: You could call Vietnam Airlines and explain to them that you mistakenly entered your passport number. They can change it for you. If you are traveling internationally, they'll most likely check your passport information at the counter anyways.

Comment: The Brazil law allow you to change only the name. You can change others information, but you will need to pay. Again, it is the BR law and how the airlines works here.

Comment: @SheikPaul I would respectfully disagree on the narrow point about asking Expedia. If you go to Expedia you may well get an incorrect answer from someone who isn't properly trained to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I contacted Expedia first. The staff on the phone said he believes it would not be a problem, but if I feel uneasy, he would report the number to Vietnam Airlines.

Actually, it seemed to me that the staff also didn't know much about what to do. So I just informed him of my new passport number and hung up the phone.

I also asked my friend who is a flight attendant of Vietnam Airlines, and she said I can just contact Vietnam Airlines and change it for free.

I'm still not sure which I should contact first in these cases, but it may be true that both are fine.

Comment: How is this an accepted answer when it's still uncertain _I'm still not sure which I should contact first in these cases, but it may be true that both are fine_?

Answer (score 3):

As it's not unusual for a new passport to be issued between the time a ticket is purchased and the actual flight, it shouldn't be a problem. Carry both the old and new passports with you, just in case you're questioned about it when you check in at the airport. Your passport number is not on your ticket, it's in your passenger record and having both passports should be sufficient. You should just have to update your Expedia account.

Comment: No need to carry both passports as those numbers are never really checked. See: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-check-in-details-such-as-date-of-birth-or-passport

Comment: @JonathanReez understood, should it be marked as a dupe?

Comment: IMO yes. But I won't vote as it's borderline.

Comment: I agree, it's no problem for the airline to fix this at check in if they wish to.