# China Advanced Passenger Information

Tags: visas, air-travel, passports

I will be taking a flight to China and have booked my flight through a third party travel company. They have sent me an email confirming my flight but also requesting that I navigate to a webpage on their site and enter Advanced Passenger Information for the authorities in China. I don't remember ever having to do this for a trip to China before; I *believe* this has always been done for me when I arrive at the airport.

So my question is: do I need to fill in this information now, or can I wait until I get to the airport and let staff there fill in the information?

I have some concerns which are not entirely related but make me (irrationally?) want to wait; I have to use 2 passports because my Chinese visa is in a recently expired passport and I have a new passport which is now valid. I've not done this before and although I've read online that it will be  fine I just want to deal with all passport issues when I'm face to face with someone at the airport.

Comment: Who is the third-party travel company?

Comment: Nobody cares if you get it right or wrong: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-check-in-details-such-as-date-of-birth-or-passport. And they do, they'll just correct it at the gate.

Comment: @MichaelC. The company is Omega Travel; I've used them in the past and know of no reason to be suspicious. It's possible that they've asked for this information in the past and I just never noticed it; it was not prominent on the email they sent to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been to China multiple times where I have both booked my ticket with the airline directly or with a third-party travel agent. I have never had to fill out a form with my passport information ahead of time. In my experience, the ticketing agent will have to check your documents ahead of time before printing your boarding pass anyways. So if it were me, I'd wait.

Comment: I'm also the type of person that doesn't like giving out information to people/company if it is not crucial. So you've already purchased the ticket, this company doesn't need to know your passport number.