# Can't check-in on Ryanair, because an adult is registered as a teen and a teen is registered as an adult

Tags: check-in, ryanair

On Ryanair online check-in, when I typed my birth date I got an error saying teens must be under 16 years old. Vice-versa for my son (I can't get it to accept the birth date because it says adults must be over 16. How can I correct this?

Comment: Could be a restriction on child or teen tickets for exit row seats. Don't you need to be an adult to use them?

Answer (score 13):

I arrived at the airport earlier and talked to the person at the check-in counter. It was indeed the case that I was registered as a teen and my son as an adult. They cleared everything up on the spot. They switched our data, correcting the mistake; however, we had to check-in at the airport (free of charge) on both the out flight and the return flight.

Answer (score 5):

You need to contact Ryanair to sort this out - I have no idea why they do this as there is no fare difference between a teen and an adult ticket.

Ryanair's number is different depending on where you are, but they are all available [on their website](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/contact-us/where-are-you-calling-from).

Comment: Thank you. I'm worried that they will charge their 110€ (x2) to switch names. I will try to call them, or arrive early at the airport to sort this out.

Comment: @andrepd that depends on whose fault it is - it would seem the wrong names were entered for each ticket at time of purchase, so if that isn't due to a Ryanair issue then you might indeed have a charge pending unfortunately. There is no other way to solve this - only Ryanair can adjust the info.

Comment: The thing is that when you make the reservation there is no indication of which names are the adult's and which are the teen's. I just now checked this myself by going through the reservation process in their website.

Comment: @andrepd an excellent argument to make to Ryanair :) Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I will update the post when/if I have a satisfactory conclusion.

Comment: @andrepd I would also screenshot (or make a video demo) of this process, in case you need to prove it to a third party.

Comment: Yes, I already did that in case I had to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use the correct month and day, but type in the wrong year of birth. Airlines [don't really care](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-check-in-details-such-as-date-of-birth-or-passport) if you get those details right and if someone does notice it's always possible to correct the check in data at the airport.

Ryanair doesn't price teen tickets differently from adult tickets, so I doubt they care if someone books the wrong fare type for themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Details can be found also in the Ryanair support page:
https://help.ryanair.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360017683717-Changing-a-Passenger-Type, where they state the age ranges for the different categories (Adult: 16 and over, Teen: 12 to 15, Child: 2 to 11, Infant: less than 2) and point you to Customer Support for changing the type - which can be done over a web chat.

Note though, that if any of the other passengers has successfully checked in already, then (as of today) they cannot amend the type of any passenger in same the booking. As an alternative, they gave us a 'free airport check-in' , so we can check-in at the counter and get everything sorted.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this problem ring Ryanair customer services.

I  had the same problem, I booked a 16 year old as a teen and a teen (14 year old) as an adult.   I panicked, especially after reading a lot of the forums, saying it would be a nightmare to change, will cost me money, and I will have to go to the airport 4 hours early.
I did have to wait awhile in the queue when I phoned Ryanair but when I did get through it was all sorted for me. The Ryanair emomployee was very helpful, explained what I did wrong, and also checked all the other passengers for me.

Comment: yes i had same problem, just ring them up and they will change fare type FOC,