# Do I need to provide passport details when booking to travel via ferry or train from England to Netherlands?

Tags: tickets, international-travel, netherlands, england

Are you required to provide passport details when booking on shuttle train or ferry to the Netherlands?

Comment: A much more important question is whether or not those details are checked by anyone: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-check-in-details-such-as-date-of-birth-or-passport

Comment: Traveled from Hull to Rotterdam in March, didn't give passport details and my mate spelt my name wrong on the booking, they didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have an complete answer, I think you are quite unlikely to be asked for a passport number when booking this journey. Nationals from the EEA and Switzerland [don't even need a passport](https://www.eurostar.com/rw-en/travel-info/travel-planning/travel-documents) for travelling to the UK or the Netherlands.

As a test I tried to make a booking for a ferry and an eurostar (train) trip and neither asked me for passport details. See the images below for what the details are you need to provide:

Eurostar:
[image: Eurostar booking]

Stena ferries:
[image: Stena ferries]