# I am a citizen of three countries. I am going to travel to not two but all three countries. How do I book the tickets, on which passports?

Tags: air-travel, passports, australian-citizens, south-african-citizens, moroccan-citizens

Australia to South Africa to Morocco. All travels are 4-5 days apart. So which ticket do I book with which passport? Which passport do I use to enter and exit to the next country?

Comment: No problem, just take all three.  You need no visas.

Comment: If a country has exit controls, exit using that country's passport.  And always enter a country using that country's passport, if you're a citizen.  (I'm not sure what country you mean by "ma", by the way.)

Comment: Do all countries allow you to have all three nationalities?

Comment: MA is the ISO 3166 code for Morocco.

Comment: The only challenge here is if you are booking all tickets as one trip, and have to provide passport # (not just the name), while booking site offers you just one field. In that case, pick one. You should be good as long as you have all passports in your possession.

Comment: @Alexander actually, you can type in whatever you want into that field as nobody ever checks it. See: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-details-entered-during-online-check-in-such-as-da/79677#79677

Comment: FWIW probably "Malaysia", @JimMacKenzie

Comment: "while booking site offers you just one field", well, it's so common that expedia for instance of course understands having up to like 10 passports  :)

Comment: @JimMacKenzie: that advice doesn't necessarily apply to all countries. Some countries have no issue with their citizens entering and exiting on a foreign passport (for short stays, at least). An example that I know well is that of Argentina. I would expect that the same is true in the Schengen area, probably the whole European union.

Answer (score 21):

This answer assumes that each of the countries allows you to be a citizen of the other two countries, and that your name is the same in all three passports.

It doesn't usually matter what passport you give the airline when you book the ticket.  You can generally check in for different flights on the same ticket using different passports.

Each time you check in, show the passport of the country where you will arrive at the end of that trip, even if that's not the passport you used to enter the country you're leaving.  If you are using another passport for visa-free transit, or if you used another passport to enter the country you're leaving, show the relevant passport to the airline if they ask about it.  If the agent looks concerned, you can offer to show the passport without waiting for a question.

For each country you visit, pick one passport and stick with it.  Always show that passport to officials of that country.  For countries of which you are a citizen, use the passport of that country.

In truth, it's really not that different from [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52100/19400); it's only slightly complicated by the fact that there are three countries rather than two.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, you don’t need a passport when booking a ticket.

You will need a passport to *check in*, be it online or in the airport. At this time, simply always use the passport of the country you are flying to.
The airline is not concerned about your citizenship(s), they are concerned *that you are allowed to enter the country at the destination*. If you show a passport from that country, you are obviously good to go there, and that’s all they care about.

Comment: In my experience, I've _always_ been asked to enter at least my name, some form of ID number and nationality when booking a ticket.

Comment: @zundi it must depend on the airline's systems, or perhaps those of the booking service you're using.  I've never been required to provide these details at the time of booking.  I've sometimes been asked to, but I've been able to book without the passport.  I don't usually have my passport available when I'm booking international travel.

Comment: Last name, First name _for sure_. This locks the ticket to that person. But I never enter anything else. I have booked about 30 flights this year already, and never entered passport information or even nationality.

Comment: Depending on the destinations, it's sometimes necessary to supply [APIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_Passenger_Information_System) data before check-in (especially if you're going to be checking in at the airport), and while it's possible to supply it at some point in between booking and check-in it's often convenient to supply it at booking.

Comment: This is just wrong.   The simplest example is **expedia.com** which (if I'm not mistaken) is the single largest seller of air tickets, in many regions.  In expedia, you have to completely enter all information from all passports before proceeding.

Comment: I don’t buy at expedia, but typically directly with each airline (cheaper). None of them enforces it. I bought over 30 tickets in 2018 already, for different people, from/to 5 different countries, and I haven’t entered a single passport info. Maybe _some_ situations require it, but definitely not all. And _maybe_ expedia’s website is too dumb and simply requests it all the time, but that would be expedia, not a standard requirement. Just book somewhere else, or type in made-up numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, in my experience immigration inspection and booking a ticket are two completely different things. I've never had an immigration inspection officer check what passport nationality I inputted when I bought the ticket. I'm not sure if any country even has a system for checking that.

Comment: Many airlines will check your passport for international travel, simply because they're the ones who are liable to fly you back should you not be allowed to pass through the border.

Comment: True. But, it's not a big deal to explain to them about your dual nationality. The people employed to check people in are not part of the immigration inspection at the arrival country, so this should not result in any problems.

Answer (score -1):

I have dual but not triple citizenship and I used to travel a lot for business so I had to do some research, but as I am not from any of the countries you have listed, you can take my advice only as a suggestion of facts you need to find for yourself.

The most important point is that you can not claim the protection of any other country in a country for which you claim to be a citizen. In other words, you can not use your South African passport in Australia and vice versa. In practice, this means you can not travel on two passports at the same time.  You can carry other passports with you, but you can't change passport half way through a journey so I would strongly recommend that you keep the extras in sealed envelopes from before departure until after arrivals. If immigration are opening sealed envelopes, you have bigger problems to deal with then having extra passports.

Since it is easier to leave a country that you are a citizen of as a foreigner then it is to arrive as one, I would recommend you break you journey into legs so that you can travel on the passport of the country that you are going to. That said, countries requiring exit visas for their own citizens can be a problem but I don't think that should affect you. Talk to their counsel for each of the countries and ask their advice before you travel. There is another reason to talk to the counsels of the different countries rather then get the advice from strangers on the interwebs, and that is that some countries charge tax based on residency. If you arrive on one passport and leave on another, then their tax office might not know that you have left and decide that you owe them money.

Comment: Some countries don't care if their citizens arrive with other countries' passports; the UK is a notable example. But even if we accept that one cannot use the South African passport in Australia and vice versa, that directly contradicts your assertion that "you can't change passport halfway through a journey": traveling between the two countries *requires* you to do that. I'm speaking from personal experience; I do this all the time without trouble.

Comment: Indeed phoog, this answer is somewhat confused.

Comment: @phoog, all I can say is that you have been lucky. most times it is never checked but my personal experience of trying to enter a country with a different passport from my ticket is not something I want to repeat. Also your assertion about the uk not caring is wrong, like most other countries they have seperate queues for uk/eu citizens and others, because they do care. They care a lot!

Comment: @PaulSmith which country was it?  My principle is to check in for each leg of the flight with the passport I'm going to use at the destination.  So when I leave the US for the EU, I check in with my EU passport. So if immigration checks the manifest, there's no discrepancy. When I check in for the return flight, I use my US passport. What I mean about the UK not caring is that they explicitly disavow any rule that British citizens must use UK passports to enter the country, unlike e.g. the United States. This has little to do with the existence of separate immigration queues.

Comment: @phoog, that is exactly what I said; "travel on the passport of the country that you are going to". However, this is not always possible. eg. US law insists US passport holders enter AND LEAVE on US passports. So arriving into the UK on a US passport requires satisfying visa requirements etc. that a UK citizen would not need to meet.

Comment: @PaulSmith When isn't it possible? Your US example does not make sense: the US does not require its citizens to enter other countries with US passports. In fact, the law only requires US citizens to "bear" a valid US passport on entry and exit; there's nothing in that law requiring them to show it to anyone, and nobody asks to see it on exit. I routinely leave the US without showing my US passport to anyone, although if the US were to institute passport checks on exit then I would of course show the US passport there. When I fly back to the US, I of course use my US passport.

Comment: @phoog, I have never in my adult life managed to get into international departures for any airport in the world without showing a valid passport. I don't believe that you have either.

Comment: The US doesn't have an "international departures" area in its airports, which is one reason why all transit passengers have to clear immigration. There is only a secure "depatures-and-domestic-arrivals" area from which both international and domestic flights depart. To get past the security screening, which includes an identity check, I normally show my foreign passport, but sometimes I use my driver's license.