# Can I book an international flight with my national ID number?

Tags: passports, international-travel, bookings

I am planning to go to India with a friend. I wanted to book the flights, but my friend's passport being certificated. Can I book her flight with her ID (we are from Spain)? I know that she will need the passport to make the visa but we wanted to book the flight as early as possible.

I guess that the actual question should be, do airlines care about what identification is used in your booking?

Comment: I don't know whether airlines care about that but I just would try to book tickets and see the result.

Comment: @Neusser, Yeah but I am a student I can not risk 600€.....

Comment: Why do you think you risk anything?

Comment: @Neusser Well I am worried that when I get to the counter to make the checking they tell that I won't be able to flight due to airline passport/ID policy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need ID to book a flight unless you're physically at an airline counter or travel agent.  And even then, you just need any valid ID, not necessarily a Passport.

The ticket must be issued in the name that matches your Passport/ID.

You only need a valid Passport or other travel docs to actually travel.  Meaning, enter the airport terminal and board the aircraft.

It is vary common for new travelers to book travel while awaiting a new Passport.  However, be aware that if you or your companion are unable to obtain a Passport before departure, the airline is not obligated to refund any non-refundable fare.

Answer (score 2):

Most websites don't ask for your passport details at booking time, so all you need to know in advance are the names of all the passengers traveling on the ticket you're purchasing. Otherwise you can type in whatever random information you want into the passport-related fields as the airline [never verifies those details](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-details-entered-during-online-check-in-such-as-da) when you get to the airport.

Just make sure you have a passport for the day of the actual flight as India doesn't accept European ID cards for entry.