# What visa details have to be included in the airline records?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, bookings, hong-kong

I have purchased online air tickets for my journey from Bengaluru to San Francisco and return through Cathy Pacific. The journey consists of 4 flights:

Outward Journey:
1. From Bengaluru to Hong Kong by flight No. KA153 on 4.9.2018
2. From Hong Kong to San Francisco by connecting flight No. CX870 on the same day with 4 hours 35 minutes waiting at Hong Kong airport

Return Journey:
1. From San Francisco to Hong Kong by flight No. CX879 on 11.11.2018
2. From Hong Kong to Bengaluru by connecting flight No. KA154 on 12.11.2018 with 2 hours 10 minutes waiting at Hong Kong airport.

I have an Indian passport and US visa.

I have entered the travel documents details as follows:

Particulars of my passport for all the four flights and US visa details in both  outward journey tickets and one return ticket from San Francisco to Hong Kong only, not for the journey from Hong Kong to Bengaluru.

Is this correct or am I required to enter the visa details for all four flights? I am confused and need clarification.

Comment: @TheZealot Posting answers as comments circumvents the voting mechanism. This advice is misleading. APIS needs to be supplied days in advance of a flight. If that doesn't happen, boarding can be denied.

Comment: @MJeffryes Advanced Passenger Information can virtually always be submitted at check in. Otherwise one would not be able to purchase last minute tickets. I have always supplied my APIS at the counter and never been denied boarding in any of the tens of flights I take into and out of the USA each year.

Comment: @TheZealot maybe that’s true for some airlines, but your “do not worry” answer could be very damaging in some cases, and since you’ve posted it as a comment it can’t be properly voted on or discussed

Comment: @MJeffryes I will delete it to avoid anxiety etc although I stand by it. Going forward you can flag comments you believe are false and misleading.

Answer (score 1):

For airlines, the passenger name record (PNR) database has basic information (name, ticketing, itinerary) but can also include information required by many countries (e.g., date of birth, gender, passport details).

Prior to boarding, airlines use the [IATA Timatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timatic) database system to verify that passengers have the required documents (e.g., passport, visa, health) for their destination and any transit point(s).

The governments of the United States, United Kingdom, and Canada require that all airlines collect [Advanced Passenger Information (API/APIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_Passenger_Information_System)) from all passengers prior to travel (within 72 hours prior to departure if booked in advance, or at time of booking if made less than 72 hours prior).

APIS asks for all names as written in your passport, gender, date of birth, nationality, country of residence; passport number, country of issue, and expiry date. You are not required to provide any other documentary information.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is [absolutely irrelevant](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-details-entered-during-online-check-in-such-as-da) what details you put into check in (or ticket purchase) forms, outside of your name. Nobody cares about them and airlines just throw away whatever you entered during check-in when they swipe your passport at the gate.

However for flights outbound to the US you can make your life a tiny bit easier by entering the correct details of whatever passport contains your US visa. This would allow you to check in online rather than checking in at the airport, although that's not a big time saver if you have checked in luggage and selected your seat in advance. On the flight back to India you can enter whatever you want to the check in form and it won't affect anything as India doesn't require airlines to verify visas before online check-in.

Enjoy your flight :)