# How to buy a flight ticket when holding an Estonian alien passport?

Tags: passports

Am wondering how can I travel to another country when holding an alien passport
[image]

Which country should I say am from? Estonia in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Often you have a field about your nationality and one with the travel document. Possibly with the type of travel document, so that check could be made. [Not all passport of a country are equally recognized (e.g. diplomatic, temporary and humanitarian).

Comment: Where do you want to travel to? An Alien’s passport gives you visa-free access to a number of countries https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Estonian_non-citizens. If you need a visa, there may be a ‘stateless’ option

Comment: France and Germany...

Answer (score 2):

You can travel to France and Germany without a visa for [90 out of every 180 days](http://reisitargalt.vm.ee/kas-ma-vajan-viisat/). (The bottom of this page also lists other countries where you can travel without a visa using the alien's passport.)

When booking your flight with the airline, you may enter your passport country as Estonia and your passport number as it is printed on your personal data page. If the airline website lets you choose between "Passport" and "Alien's passport" then you can choose the latter, otherwise choose "Passport". Note that your machine readable section begins with `P<EST`. The P followed by 3 letter country code is the same worldwide for all passports, and it is the same as Estonia citizen passports. Other types of travel documents such as 1951 convention travel documents have a different first letter code here.

But [it really doesn't matter much what you put in the airline website](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-details-entered-during-online-check-in-such-as-da); it will be verified when you check in for your flight anyway.