# Travel to India with Indian passport having less than 6 months validity

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens, passports, air-india

I have an international flight this Friday (25 Sep 2020) from San Francisco to Delhi. The airline is Air India.  I am trying to do web check in (and health undertaking) on Air India website but it fails with the error - passport not valid for the required minimum duration. My passport expiry date is 14 March 2021, less than 6 months left for expiry.

Does the minimum of six months passport validity rule applies to Indian citizens travelling to India? I think it should be fine for Indian citizens coming back to India with less than 6 months left on their passport. I will be renewing my passport in India.

Comment: Is this a direct flight, or is there an intermediate stop somewhere?

Comment: It is a direct flight.

Comment: Timatic says you should be fine, which is what I expected. This is probably just a glitch with the Air India web site. You should probably call the airline. You might have to check in at the airport.

Comment: Just enter a different expiry date during check-in. It doesn't matter in the end: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-details-entered-during-online-check-in-such-as-da?r=SearchResults

Comment: The glitch still exists in the system blocking Indian citizens from checking in online as of Oct 22, 2021. Surprised that they don’t have a fix in place already or that they didn’t consider the rule exemption in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

The six months passport validity rule does not apply to Indian citizens traveling to India.

Answer (score 2):

My son travelled to Delhi from Chicago on Dec 11' 2021 and his passport was valid till April 2022. He has an OCI card. The passport has to be valid for the duration of stay per the United Website and that is what the agent asked us at the gate. No issues with immigration.

Comment: N Verma, So, I guess your son had a US passport with a validity of less than 6 months. And this was a non-stop flight with United Airlines ?