# Can I travel to India (from the UK) if my Indian passport is about to expire in 3 days from the date of departure?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, international-travel, india

My India passport expires on 16.02.22 and I intend to travel from the UK to India on 13.02.22. Will this cause any problems in travel?

Comment: Do you have a direct flight or do you need to transit somewhere. Your passport is good to enter India if it is not expired but transit points may have a limit on validity period.

Comment: If no transit, then we have a duplicate [Travel to India with Indian passport having less than 6 months validity](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/159511)

Comment: It is a direct flight. And I hope to arrive in India and then renew my passport for returning back to the UK.

Comment: Thank you very much. That answers my question.