# Wrong nationality on boarding pass due to IT error

Tags: air-travel, tickets

**TL;DR** How can I make sure I board my flight when the boarding pass shows my nationality wrong due to an IT error?

I've just checked in online for my flight tomorrow and upon checking my boarding pass details, it looks like my nationality is wrong (ISO 3166 alpha-2 code is obviously wrong). I am 100% sure it was not my mistake, in fact i can access the details and technically change them, but they are already correct, and my changes are not being reflected in the boarding pass that is being generated.

The customer service department is closed so I can't reach them. I have screenshots of the form and I sent a support email, but I don't expect to hear back from them until my flight first thing tomorrow.

I am flying from the UK into the EU.

Comment: @CGCampbell I don't have access to editing tools atm. Is there anythng in particular you'd like to verify?

Comment: actually, from doing a google search, this appears to be a common enough problem. It looks like the answer would be to not worry about it, just check in at the airport with your passport in hand 15 minutes early and get the person at the desk to change it. Disregard my request from earlier (was only to see the pass and error, to perhaps give a lead on what to do.)

Comment: CGCampbell I am aware that mangled names typically get sorted without issues, so that gives me some peace of mind that this problem will be resolved in a similar fashion. Given the circumstances, it looks like I have no option but to show up at the airport and hope for the best.

Comment: Are you sure those two letters are supposed to be nationality?  I don't recall that nationality has been listed on boarding passes I've had in the past.  Is it possible it's a two-letter code for something unrelated, that just happens to coincide with some country's ISO 3166 code?

Comment: @NateEldredge 100%. It's the value of the "Nationality" field. On top of it, the form showed many oddities when I started the check in process, for example that country was selected by default, plus other weird default values in other fields.

Comment: "How can I make sure I board my flight when the boarding pass shows my nationality wrong due to an IT error?" - arrive at the airport a little earlier and ask at the check-in counter showing your phone or print-out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-details-entered-during-online-check-in-such-as-da. TL;DR it **absolutely** doesn't matter what you enter during online check-in, except for your name. It will get corrected at the gate.

Comment: I don’t think I’ve ever seen nationality on a boarding pass. What airline is this, and what are the origin and destination countries? Also not quite sure why it would need to be shown on a boarding pass, especially since you could declare anything you want, until it’s checked by someone it’s not worth the electrons it’s shown with.

Comment: What airline?  I too have never seen a boarding pass with a "nationality" field.  What airports?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For UK/USA bound flights, are details entered during online check-in, such as date of birth or passport number ever checked by airlines/immigration?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-details-entered-during-online-check-in-such-as-da)

Answer (score 2):

An image of what you’re questioning might help, but I suspect it’s a code for the airline.

Most, if not all, of the boarding passes I’ve seen in my six years of frequent flying have been the same format.  I’ve discarded most, but those of my trip yesterday have only one two-letter code on them, and that’s AA, meaning American Airlines.  I don’t think I’ve ever seen my nationality on a boarding pass.

[IATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association) has given each of their 290 member airlines a [two-character code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airline_codes).  AA for American Airlines is pretty plain; DL for Delta, not so much.  ZK for Great Lakes Airlines, not a bit.

Comment: I made a comment on my main post with extra details. It's not the airline code.

Comment: IOS trying to “help”

Comment: @WGroleau is that comment about iOS in response to my (now deleted) comment about "six months of frequent flying" sounding hectic?  I should have known.  Autocorrect is an endless source of amusement.  And of frustration.  More frustration than amusement, I suppose, on balance, but I'll take the amusement where I can.