# Wrong ID information on Wizzair

Tags: air-travel, passports, tickets, airlines, wizz-air

I have a flight on the 25th of August and it’s my first time flying alone and I’m terrified, with that anxiety I wrote my document information wrong. Instead of writing my ID document number I wrote my personal number. I can’t do anything but cry now I am so devastated and so scared. I payed so much for this im so so scared. Please if someone could help me. Has this happened to you if so how did you fix it. Will they be able to fix it? It’s a detail that you can see on the ticket so they will check. I don’t want to have any problems I am so scared

Comment: With most airlines you can change your ID details up to the last minute via the "manage my booking" section of the website, did you try that?

Comment: Strongly related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-details-entered-during-online-check-in-such-as-da

Answer (score 4):

As outlined in the answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-details-entered-during-online-check-in-such-as-da), airlines don’t have the slightest concern for any fields that you enter other than “name”. Every other detail on the booking could be completely wrong and they’ll still let you on the plane. As you enter the plane, your passport or ID card will be scanned by the agent, updating your booking to contain the right data and overwriting any data previously recorded for your booking. This also ensures that any APIS data is correctly shared with immigration authorities.

Relax and enjoy your flight. There’s nothing else you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Airline staff can't be arsed about ID details. They have more important stuff to do, and are not paid to check ID document details, other than quickly verifying that the boarding passenger is the one named on the ticket. They only collect ID details in order to share with immigration authorities of the destination country in advance should those authorities require it (many don't).

Besides, people are always free to use a different ID document, get a new passport even on the day of departure, and so on. Your air carriage contract only requires you to present a valid ID document before boarding, nothing more.

So, rest relaxed.