# Wrong ID expiration date entered on Kiwi reservation

Tags: paperwork, id

When I made a reservation for a return flight with WizzAir from Romania to Italy through Kiwi I entered the wrong expiration date, not something big, but a typo. The date that was entered was 10.10.2029; it should have been 12.10.2029.

Is this likely to cause a problem at check in?

Comment: Most airlines allow you to edit this as much as you want. Did you check the “manage my booking” section of their website to see if that was possible?

Comment: @gerrit: probably kiwi.com. Popular (but fairly questionable) online travel agency. Avoid if possible

Comment: I have the confirmation number and I entered it on the airline's website, but it's not showing any section about changing the expiration date of my ID. I'll tell you how it goes when I get at the airport :). And yes, avoid Kiwi.com as much as possible. Maybe only use it to compare prices and finding flights, but that's it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As outlined in the answer to [For UK/USA bound flights, are details entered during online check-in, such as date of birth or passport number ever checked by airlines/immigration?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-details-entered-during-online-check-in-such-as-da), airlines don't care in the slightest about any fields you enter during reservation or check in other than your name. You can put in the wrong birthday, passport number, passport expiration date, etc, and you'll still be allowed on board, though sometimes online check-in might fail if you're traveling to a foreign country, and you'll have to check-in at the airline's departures desk.

So if I were you I'd not worry about it and show up for my flight as usual. No need to fix it, unless it's super easy to do in the booking management website.

Comment: Though it might be a problem if you use a self printing ticket service station at the airport that uses your passport for authentication.

Comment: @Zibelas: No, not really. The ID/passport MUST match, and the kiosk will then ask you to indicate your first hop as a "security" measure. That's it. When I implemented this for Amadeus a decade ago we asked if more matching should be done, and the answer was mostly no: the other fields are too unreliable (names being the worse) to be counted on. Even the "expiration date" is unreliable for a number of countries (such as South Korea on military IDs) as extensions are done by "sticky", and the stream is left unmodified.

Comment: @MatthieuM. yes that should be the case, nevertheless there are countless models and different budgets. People with a tight connection who count on self ticket machines might just get stuck on it for a bit too long because of not matching data.

Comment: @Zibelas: I've regularly had failures with passports and ID cards, mostly when the stream cannot be read properly. Always write down your PNR and e-ticket numbers. Also... print all boarding passes before departure, not to have to worry about that during connections, and if you do not book all flights through a single airline (alliance) make sure to have ample time for the connection.

Comment: @Zibelas it happens even if all the details are correct :) In that case you go to the counter.

Answer (score 6):

You can edit passenger details but they are likely going to charge for it "depending on your service level".

See [Can I correct traveler details? (Kiwi.com)](https://www.kiwi.com/us/help/changing-or-correcting-traveler-details-268/article/can-i-correct-traveler-details-77/)

Recommendation: If any possible, book with the airline directly. If an online travel agency (OTA) is substantially cheaper, use a reputable one. In my opinion, Kiwi is NOT reputable. I suggest reading reviews and form your own opinion.

Comment: If OP gets hold of the actual PNR they can probably make the changes directly on the airline’s website without any service charge.